# \caption* does not work properly

Tags: captions, algorithms

I have a problem with using the command `\caption*` (from the `caption` package) together with the algorithm environment. Instead of parsing the `\caption*` as a single command, it is parsed like `\caption` with parameter "*". Any ideas?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{caption}
\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}[H]
\caption*{This should be an unnumbered caption.}
\begin{algorithmic}
  \State $0 \gets 0$
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem.

Comment: Sorry, I have edited the question.

Comment: That us not a minaimal example. Post something that others can copy'n'paste directly without having to add anything.

Comment: I have edited the question once again.

Comment: Your example code works as expected on my system. Perhaps you are using an outdated LaTeX system? What LaTeX distribution do you use?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina In deed, the problem has been solved by updating the `caption` package. If you post this as an answer, I may accept it.

Comment: @042 I am glad to hear that the problem has been solved. If the problem was simply outdated package(s), we usually close the question as "too localized", so there's no need to write an answer an accept it.